# Excel Data Validation List using formula with filtering

Tags: excel, excel-formula, validation

I have following workbook:

Worksheet **Accounts**:

[image: Accounts worksheet]

Worksheet **Posts**:

[image: Posts worksheet]

I would like to know if it is possible to define Data Validation of type List to entire column **B** in sheet **Posts** using formula, so that Data Validation popup shows only Account **Ids** from **Accounts** sheet which **Website** column matches **Website** column of a selected row in **Posts** sheet and which have value *Active* in **Status** column?

In SQL-ish or LINQ-ish words:

> SELECT Id FROM Accounts WHERE Website =
>   @SelectedPostRow.Website AND Status = Active

Marks on the second image shows which values should be shown in a drop-down.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do this, but it requires some supporting setup.

First for each of your website options, you need to create a named range for the options that would be in the drop down you are seeking to create.

To do this, just highlight the list of cells and right click, the choose Name a Range

Then you need to create a lookup list for your website names to the named range possiblities

Then in your data validation source use a forumla like this:

```
=indirect(vlookup(a1,$i$8:$j$13,2,false))
```

then whala, the dropdown list changes based upon the website value.

Now if you are also needing to automate the named range bits, you could change them to encompass entire columns and then use a pivot table to pull in the data.  Would just need
an independant pivot for each website option.

Each time you pulled in fresh data you would need to refresh the pivots, but it would function.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, I must create a named range of Account Ids for each Website value. This won't work for me since Accounts sheet can be additionally populated with new accounts and I do not want to increase named range every time this happens. Pivot also wouldn't work because it would require refreshing. I want this to be completely automated with no additional bookkeeping tasks involved. And what about Status = Active part?

Comment: The pivot table would be what you need to do the Status = Active piece.  Also Pivots can be refreshed via VBA, which can be automated.

Answer (score 3):

This problem need a bit of a preparation.
In the same sheet, or in another, copy your data (or add the relevant cells)

In column A you have a number that could be ranked. 
I obtained it with (cell A2):

> =IF(C2=$J$2,1,0)*IF(E2="Active",1,0)*ROW()

In column B rank the number and exclude the unwanted rows (B2):

> =IF(A2=0,0,RANK(A2,A:A))

Then you can VLOOKUP in column H, using a enum in column G (manually entered). The formula for H1:

> =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G2,$B$2:$D$9,3,FALSE),"")

Now you could set your validation based on column H

[image: screenshot]

PS: there could be small errors in the formulas as I have translated them from italian and I cannot test in english.