# Allowing 2 Forms Of Data Validation In A Single Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, validation

Without using VBA, is it possible to have the data validation of a cell differ depending on the contents of another cell? For example, if "Yes" is entered into cell A1, then A2 is populated with a list of items. If on the other hand "No" is entered into A1, then A2 allows any value.

I can source different lists depending on the contents of the cell using the following formula as the Source in Data Validation:

```
=IF(A1="","",IF(A1="Yes",Sheet1!$C$1:$C$4,Sheet1!$D$1:$D$6))
```

However I am not sure whether this could be disabled completely if A1 is blank. Using the above formula, leaving A1 blank would not allow you to enter free text into the cell and attempting to do so would result in a data validation error.

Comment: I'm not totally sure if I get your question right, but this might serve as a solution for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218332/excel-data-validation-list-using-formula-with-filtering?rq=1

Comment: Thanks @Tom, but that's a slightly different question. I am looking for a way to change the data validation TYPE (i.e. Any Value or List) depending on the contents of a cell rather than change the contents of a list depending on the contents of a cell.

Comment: I can't think of a way to dynamically change the type of validation in a cell without using VBA

Comment: Yeah, I thought you could do a little workaround. Have 2 tables with either the list of items and another one referencing to the other values. Then depending on A1 your list is populated with the according table. (Not totally sure if this works, but how do you want to populate your list if any value is allowed anyways?)

Answer (score 0):

Use the **INDIRECT** function. If the other cell contains a named range's name, then the dropdown will contain cells from the range.
There are forbidden characters but otherwise it works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer the question - see my comments above. I am looking to dynamically change the type of validation and not the range in the list. The latter would be dynamically changing the list in a single type of validation, which is not what I am trying to do.